# Imagick liquidrescaleimage method exception

Tags: php, image, exception, image-processing, imagick

Imagick hosting is configured with version ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2012-12-14 Q16, but I get the exception when I use liquidrescaleimage method.

The exception is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'delegate library support not built-in `/tmp/magick-XXzvCR7g' (LQR) @
>   resize.c/LiquidRescaleImage/1549' in /host/multimedia.php:142 Stack
>   trace: #0 /host/multimedia.php(142): Imagick->liquidrescaleimage(1024,
>   768, 3, 25) #1 {main} thrown in /host/multimedia.php on line 142

The lines of code that generate this exception are:

```
$im = new Imagick("../../../../../resources/course/" . $id . "/multimedia/" . $value['multimedia']);
$im->liquidrescaleimage(1024, 768, 3, 25);
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile Image Magick yourself with the option `–with-lqr` enabled.

You will need to download the liquid rescale library to allow ImageMagick to be compile against it either from a repository or from the source available on it's [website](http://liblqr.wikidot.com/).

Comment: I do not think you have permission to recompile the library

Comment: _I_ don't have permission? I'm pretty sure I recompile that library on my server.

Comment: The server is not mine, I bought the web space for a web site.